# SQL ALchemy: Constuct or_ with dynamic list of conditionals

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am building a sports web app. I want a query that takes a list of players, and checks whether their game for that week has started yet.

The following query works for me, but I need to explicitly type out each player in the list. If I want my list to be dynamically sized, this will not work. Is there anything I can construct this query in a smarter way?

SQL Alchemy query:

```
db.session.query(Game.start).filter(Game.week_id == self.week_id).filter(or_(Game.home_team == self.players[1].team, Game.away_team == self.players[1].team, Game.home_team == self.players[0].team, Game.away_team == self.players[0].team)).all()
```

The query then looks like this:

```
SELECT game.start AS game_start 
FROM game
WHERE game.week_id = %(week_id_1)s 
  AND (%(param_1)s = game.home_team_name OR 
       %(param_2)s = game.away_team_name OR 
       %(param_3)s = game.home_team_name OR 
       %(param_4)s = game.away_team_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it using in_

```
db.session.query(Game).filter(Game.week_id == self.week_id, Game.start==True).filter(or_(Game.home_team_name.in_([p.team_name for p in self.players]), Game.away_team_name.in_([p.team_name for p in self.players]))).all()
```